# Handling features not correlated with output prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, correlation, linear-regression

I do regression analysis with multiple features. Number of features is 20-23. For now, I check each feature correlation with output variable. Some features show correlation coefficient close to 1 or -1 (highly correlated). Some features show correlation coefficient near 0. My question is: do I have to remove this feature if it has close to 0 correlation coefficient? Or I can keep it and the only problem is that this feature will no make some noticeable effect to regression model or will have faint affect on it. Or removing that kind of features is obligatory?

Comment: In general there is no reason to remove any of them. Linear models are not easily confused by correlated values (I have seen problems with highly correlated variables, but this is very context specific). Additionally you can easily push the coefficients of weakly predictive features to zero by using a gaussian or laplacian prior on the weights with ridge and lasso models.

Comment: only remove if you are confident that the features showing no correlation make no sense in context of the target feature. e.g. you can ignore feature "tyre tube color" to target "bicycle price", as in reality it makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In short

- High (absolute) correlation between a feature and output implies that this feature should be valuable as predictor
- Lack of correlation between feature and output implies **nothing**

#### More details

Pair-wise correlation only shows you how one thing affects the other, it says completely nothing about how good is this feature **connected with others**. So if your model is not trivial then **you should not drop variables because they are not correlated with output**). I will give you the example which should show you why.

Consider following sample, we have 2 features (X, Y), and one output value (Z, say red is 1, black is 0)

[image]

```
X   Y   Z
1   1   1
1   2   0
1   3   0
2   1   0
2   2   1
2   3   0
3   1   0
3   2   0
3   3   1
```

Let us compute the correlations:

- CORREL(X, Z) = 0
- CORREL(Y, Z) = 0

So... we should drop all values? One of them? If we drop any variable - our prolem becomes completely impossible to model! "magic" lies in the fact that there is actually a "hidden" relation in the data.

```
|X-Y|
0
1
2
1
0
1
2
1
0
```

And

- CORREL(|X-Y|, Z) = -0.8528028654

Now this is a good predictor!

You can actually get a perfect regressor (interpolator) through

```
Z = 1 - sign(|X-Y|)
```